# Node.js Issue w/ Engine.io

Tags: node.js, npm, socket.io, node-modules

I'm having an issue with my server-side node script from processing. I have a VPS and running node app.js works perfectly fine in my other virtual folder for website1. But when i run node app.js in my website2 virtual folder it says

```
/home/website2/node_modules/engine.io/node_modules/uws/uws.js:3
const http = require('http');
^^^^^
SyntaxError: Use of const in strict mode.
    at Module._compile (module.js:439:25)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
    at Module.require (module.js:364:17)
    at require (module.js:380:17)
    at Server.init 
(/home/website2/node_modules/engine.io/lib/server.js:115:16)
    at new Server 
(/home/website2/node_modules/engine.io/lib/server.js:65:8)
    at Function.attach 
(/home/website2/node_modules/engine.io/lib/engine.io.js:123:16)
    at Server.initEngine 
(/home/website2/node_modules/socket.io/lib/index.js:274:21)
```

First, I'll

```
cd /home/website2
```

Then I'll

```
node app.js
```

Which shows me the error above, but when I

```
cd /home/website1
```

Then

```
node app.js
```

My script executes. What's the difference? I checked my node version and its 0.10.30, but it works in my website1 home directory regardless. How can I fix this?

Comment: v0.10.30 is ancient and I don't think the recent socket.io/engine.io version support that old a node.js version.  I'm not even sure it supports `const`.  I'm guessing you're not running that version or either node.js or of socket.io/engine.io in the directory where it works.

Comment: Update your node version :)